# JSONAPI Delete Relationship

Tags: go, json-api

JSONAPI spec specifies the way to delete a relationships is via a `PATCH` request with the following body:

```
{ "data": null }
```

However, I don't see any way of doing this with the [JSONAPI library by Google](https://github.com/google/jsonapi).

When ever I try to pass that body, I get the error:

> data is not a jsonapi representation

which comes from [this line](https://github.com/google/jsonapi/blob/master/request.go#L145) in the source.

The thing is, I see nothing in `unmarshalNode` or `UnmarshalPayload` that handles the fact that `data` is `null`. Further more, because this is a generic `recover` the actual error is a `nil reference` error, because it assumes `data` exists with something.

Is there any way of actually doing a `PATCH` request with `null` data?

Comment: Do I assume correctly that you are trying to update a has-one relationship using a relationship link?

Comment: This is a PATCH request to nullify/delete a has one. Updating is fine as there is a request body in that instance.